# read csv data from multiple folders

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, import

I want to open csv files from multiple folders, however my code doesn't work some reason.

```
ext = ('.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame()
count = 0
subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir() if f.is_dir() ]
print(subfolders)
path = './data'
for folder in [f.path for f in os.scandir() if f.is_dir() ]:
    for folder in os.listdir(path):
        print(folder)
        for files in os.listdir((path)):
            if files.endswith(ext):
                print(files)
                df = pd.read_csv(files)
                count = count + 1 
                df['Run_number'] = count
                df['Athlete'] ='test'
                df['Date'] = files[10:18]
                df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
                cols_to_move = ['Athlete', 'Date']
                df = df[cols_to_move + [col for col in df.columns if col not in cols_to_move]] #plaats atleet en datum in eerste colommen
                data = pd.concat([data,df])
            else:
                pass
    data
```

this gives the error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<./data>/OutdoorRun20220426195118.csv

Answer (score 0):

Try to give full path of your .csv files. Such as

```
your/path/to/csv/files/yourcsvfile.csv
```